# Do physicists use a different way of dealing with Function notation?

Tags: conventions, notation, calculus

I've started studying physics concepts, in Mathematics we tend to define $f$ to be some function that we apply to a variable $x$, where as in Physics and Mechanics work I sometimes find that people often define $F$ to be the force and use notation like $F(t)$, and will perform an re-arrangement operation using a function for example the position $S(t)$ to determine what they title $F(s)$, a function which is equal to $F(t)$ as if $F$ is just a free variable and not simply denoting a function - where it perhaps should be $F(G(s))$ where $t=G(s)$ is this a mistake in my reasoning or a different way of doing things?

Comment: I followed what you said up until "a function which is equal to $F(t)$ as if $F$ is just a free variable and not a function" Perhaps you could clarify this point? Anyway, I think a straightforward answer is that yes, you're describing a common abuse of notation that physicists use.

Comment: It's just a sloppy way of doing things.

Comment: It's more convenient and usually it's obvious what's going on. When you're solving a dynamics problem, for example, you might run into $a(t)$, $a(x)$, and $a(v)$ at different points. If you had to call these different letters, we would run out of the alphabet for even basic questions.

Comment: It's just like how mathematicians dislike working with coordinate-dependent quantities in the context of differential geometry; they don't like tensor components because a tensor is a geometric object "out there", independent of how you describe it. Similarly, for us, force is a physical object "out there". It doesn't really matter if you parametrize it by time or position or whatever else, so we denote those all with the same letter.

Comment: @d_b well a usually a function is a letter $f$ where $f$ is a function and not a variable that represents a particular number more just an operation that can be done on a particular number say $x$ or time $t$, sometimes I describe things poorly, I was just going to say a number, but I didn't want you to think of it as some kind of bound variable like in an integral, I've re-phrased it as 'denoting a function', interestingly enough an abuse of language from me after all this nitpicking I've been doing.

Comment: Commonly used for vector fields atleast is $\vec{F}(x,y,z) $ or $\vec{F(\vec{R})}$ to indicate that the field is to be evaluated via a position vector, which allows for the possibility of it being evalauted in  non cartesian coordinates. Or, $\vec{F}(\vec{R(t)})$ to indicate the vector field is to be evaluated along some path. Aka a moving object inside a vector field

Comment: with that notation it is absolutely fine as $F(R(t))$ is not equal to $F(t)$ but $F(R)$ and because of the $R(t)$ relation it is essentially the same mapping in a different form as with the Cartesian form of the function. but say in my example $F(S^-1(t))$ is not equal to $F(S(t)$ which we essentially try to express it as.

Answer (score 1):

I would not say that this is a particular quirk of *physicists*, rather it is something what happens when you have to talk about several similar functions that are "morally" the same but in the strict sense are different functions.

For example, when you encounter "the force" once expressed as $F(s)$ and once as $F(t)$, indeed these are two different functions in the strict sense, one from the space of spatial displacements to the space of force vectors and one from the space of temporal displacements to the space of force vectors. They are connected in that you have a (locally) invertible function $s(t)$ from the space of temporal displacements to the space of spatial displacements that describes a motion and so you can describe the force either by defining $F(s)$ and then "$F(t)$" is really $F(s(t))$ or by defining $F(t)$ and then "$F(s)$" is really $F(t(s))$, where you'll also note that we call the inverse of $s(t)$ just $t(s)$ and not $s^{-1}$ or something.

What we're physically trying to say here is that there's "a force" along "the motion". We don't really *care* whether we describe a point in the motion spatially or temporally, the two descriptions are equivalent via the invertible $s(t)$. The particulars of how the specific functions are defined in the strict sense are not always *relevant* to what we're doing, and so they are conveniently elided by this notation - but it requires being careful about how things "really" work when you have to do math like the chain rule for derivatives!

More generally, you will see this sort of elision also in other mathematical contexts where invertible functions (or more abstractly isomorphisms) are involved and the difference between a function and a function concatenated with that isomorphism becomes murky in the text: When you have $f$ and an invertible $g$, particularly when $g$ is "obvious" or "natural" in some sense, then the "difference" between talking about $f$ and $f\circ g$ or $f' := f\circ g$ and $g^{-1}\circ f'$ or whatever becomes pretty inconsequential as along as everyone is aware what's happening.

One example of this is when we talk about functions on manifolds and charts - we talk about a scalar function $f : M\to \mathbb{R}$ "on the manifold" and then someone will write down some expression e.g. $f(x_1,x_2) = x_2$ for it in a particular coordinate system but strictly speaking of course the function on the coordinate system is a function $\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ and cannot be "the same function" as $f$ but after the first week of learning how charts and coordinates work *no one* will ever use a different symbol for these two "different" functions unless it is somehow specifically relevant to their point. Think about the function $f(x,y) = x^2 + y^2$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$ and how people might also write $f(r,\theta) = r^2$ for it in spherical coordinates - if you want, you can complain we used the same symbol for formally "different" functions, but that's just not how we actually think about functions.

Comment: In the beginning when you talk of '$F(t)$' you mean in the slightly informal way that we use in physics as $F(t)$ as well as having a different mapping to '$F(s)$ is generally a different operation and as you say once we consider the dimensions map different sets in both a mathematical and intuitive sense.

Comment: It's true I've seen similar notation for vector valued functions where we refer to the arc-length parameterisation  as $F(s)$ when it probably should not be.

Answer (score 1):

You can decide for yourself how idiosyncratic the practices I summarize below are:

- $F=F(t)$ for all $t$ means there is a function $F_t$ from $t$ values to $F$ values such that, for all times $t$, $F=F_t(t)$.
- $F=F(s)$ for all $s$ means the same thing but for $s$, viz. a function $F_s$. Writing $s$ as a function $s_t$ of $t$, $F_t=F_s\circ s_t$. This equation identifies the functions $F_t,\,F_s$ in a sense, which motivates just writing $F$ all the time.
- Just for completeness: $F=F(t)$ with a specific $t$ in mind means that, for the function $F_t$ mentioned in the first bullet point, $F$ has value $F_t(t)$ at that time. Similarly with $F=F(s)$ or $s=s(t)$.

Comment: its a good way to formalise it, makes it simpler to say $F = F(t)$ and $F(t)=F(s)$ as either a function relation or identity (however you think of it) and $F=$F(s)$ as a set of relations is a nice way to do it and I understand its just for simplicity.